# Whay did LASSO fail to perform feature selection？

Tags: python, machine-learning, feature-selection, lasso-regression

I encountered a problem while doing my ML project. Hope to get some advice from you!

I fit logistic LASSO on a dataset with only 15 features trying to predict a binary outcome. I know that LASSO is supposed to do feature selection and eliminate the unimportant ones (coefficient = 0), but in my analysis, it has selected all the features and did not eliminate any one of them. My questions are:

1. Is this because I have too few features, or that the features are not correlated with each other(low co-linearity?)
2. Is this a bad thing or a good thing for a classification model?
3. some coefficients of the features LASSO selected are less than 0.1, can I interpret them as non-important or not that important to the model?

p.s. I run the model using the sklearn package in python.

Thank you!

Comment: Your question needs more clarification! Please, take a look at "How to Ask A Good Question" (stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It can help you to enhance your question.

Answer (score 0):

Lasso did not fail to perform feature selection. It just determined that none of the 15 features were unimportant. For the one's where you get coefficients = 0.1 this just means that they are less important when compared to other more important features. So I would not be concerned!

Also 15 features is not a large amount of features for Lasso to determine the important one's. I mean it depends on the data so for some datasets, it can eliminate some features from a dataset of 10 features and sometimes it won't eliminate any from a dataset of 20. It just depends on the data!

**Cheers!**